# integrate options in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

To add an options page I followed the documentation for [Creating Options Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Creating_Options_Pages&oldid=97268#See_It_All_Together_2).

But I can't integrate any custom option of my plugin. 
Suppose in  my plugin there is a shortcode and, in a section, there is a background which can be changed by custom coding. e.g ;

```
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'category' => '',
    'background'=> '#333',
    'border-width' => '10px'

), $atts, 'photo_gallery' ) );

$q = new WP_Query(
    array('photo_gallery_cat' => $category, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'photo-items')
    );


$list = '<section border="$border-width" style="background-color:'.$background.'"><ul id="gallery"><li style="background-color: '.$background.'" id="fullPreview"></li>';
while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
```

In the shortcode, I can use `background="#aaa"` to change the background color. With `border-width` also.
But I want to create a option to change this by option page. How to integrate this in option page?

Also I need to use active functions options. 
e.g this:

```
function active_least_gallery() {?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#gallery').least({
            'random': true,
            'lazyload': false,
            'scrollToGallery': false
        });
    });
</script>
```

How to use this true/false options from the option page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pull the option with `get_option('new_option_name')`. In your shortcode:

```
// #aaa is the default, if nothing is saved yet
$background = get_option( 'new_option_name', '#aaa' );
```

And for the jQuery gallery:

```
$scroll = get_option( 'some_other_option', false );
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#gallery').least({
            'scrollToGallery': <?php echo $scroll; ?>
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or use [**`wp_localize_script`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) if you're enqueuing the script.

Comment: Brasofilo ,thank you for your answer. One little problem to understand. where will the background option use ? which line i should change and replace this line ? or something other to do ? though i am new here, facing difficulty to use this.

Comment: Learning to program means **lots of trial and error**. My examples go inside the ones you provided. $backgroung goes *before* you use it inside the shortcode. Is your options page working ok?

Comment: Sorry, aarif, the information you're providing is not enough to help you. Can you read the guide [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question?